# Is there a Callback-Method, when a Grid is filled in a Telerik Grid in Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, telerik

I want to open the printer popup, when my grid is filled with data from a rest api, but when I use the method OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) the printer window opens and the grid is empty on every call. Is there a method, which get called when the grid is filled with the data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Inside of the OnInitializedAsync Method you can try send out your http request.

In the meantime you could start a Loadingscreen or something

2. Once you got an result populate your grid
3. Open the pop up window

Another option is using parallel Tasks with callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at it the other way around. The callback you are asking for should be executed at the end of the method you are fetching data with, as this is an operation that is external and is taking some time - not the render of the TelerikGrid. As for the Grid itself, it will re-render the moment you pass it a new parameter.

Have a look at the following REPL snippet and note the logging below the Grid: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QmFOQMlf082ukdUF56